# ASP: Block my broadband provider

Tags: asp-classic

This is about classic ASP.
I have found something Serious: After a few seconds I visit some pages (ASP, txt, html) in my web site my broadband provider will visit the same pages.
Do you know any ASP code to stop that?

I know I can put some ASP code to block the broadband provider's IP, but I do not know all its IPs.

I will be much appreciated for any suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by "my broadband provider will visit the same pages"? How can you tell?

Comment: The visiter's IP belongs to my broadband provider.

Comment: That just means private person using the same provider.. isn't it?

Comment: I email my broadband provider and they explained why they are doing so! How can I believe them?

Comment: Depends. What did they tell you?

Comment: They may collect any information, such as passwords, banking,..., do you think they will tell you?

Comment: You said "they explained why they are doing so". Can you please repeat what they explained so I can make my own opinion?

Comment: Or maybe they are trying to protect your from harmful websites by scanning the sites you visit...

Answer (score 0):

Guess what would happen if you block the IP range of you internet provider, your own access to your webpages will be blocked too.

You ISP could be accessing your pages automatically by a robot or something in order to create a cache.
In that case, what you can probably do is to scan the User-Agent of the visitors and only serve pages to those who are accessing your page through an actual browser such as; Chrome or Firefox and such.
But keep in mind that you will be blocking access to legit robots like Search Engine Crawlers such as Googlebot.

Anyway if you have like an admin section which you only want to be accessed by you yourself, I would suggest that you secure it by Sessions, Cookies and/or SSL connection.

Good Luck...